# Disk volume keeps going offline after being brought online via Diskpart

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partition-recovery, diskpart

So i'm having an exceptionally good time trying to fix my recovery partition.

reagentc /info shows it as disabled.

reagentc /enable returns The Windows RE image was not found.

diskpart list vol shows the recovery volume as offline.

if i bring it online, I can enable it with reagentc and it works until I restart at which point its offline again and reagentc /info shows it as disabled.

what am i doing wrong?  How can I get this to persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out somehow, someway, at some point windows turned off automount.

The solution was to use diskpart to bring the volume online.  then use it to enable automount.   then it stayed on line and persisted.